# Make a reference immutable?

Tags: java, reference, mutable

```
class Some{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  //getters and setters
}
class Check{
  private Some[] someVals;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Assume I have populated values into the someVals in Check class

```
void newMethod(){
      Check checkPrev = getCheckPopulated();
      Some[] someFirst = checkPrev.getSomeVals();
      modifySome(someFirst);
      Some[] some  = ? // at this point need the values of someFirst
   }
```

My question is to get the value of the Some[] array even after the modification(where i have specified), that is the values which were first present when assigned.

fine I will make my question clear. 
final Some[] someFirst = checkPrev.getSomeVals(); didnot work
Is there a small tip similar to final by preserving the arrays value without having to reassign all the values to another array all over again?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Any reason why you use an array and not, say, a `List`?

Comment: Because i have a similar requirement where array is used, btw what difference does it make to use a list instead of array?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the requirement is simple to get the values of the initial array even after it is modified.

Comment: Should this: `modifySome(some);` be this: `modifySome(someFirst);`?

Comment: srry I wil correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have your cake and eat it also. You have to make a deep copy of the object, and then modify the original copy. Then, the deep copy will contain the original values.

Comment: Please assure me again, is there no other workaround other than making a deep copy of the array i.e; to call the setters and getters of the Some class? And i'm good enough...

Comment: Until quantum computing comes along, yes, you will have to do this. For now, you must call the setters and getters or use Serialization.

Comment: http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/ Here is a good article on serialization. The basics of it is that you create a ByteArrayOutputStream and a ObjectOutputStream with the created ByteArrayOutputStream as the input. You can then write the object to the ObjectOutPutStream, then use a combination of ByteArrayInputStream and ObjectInputStream to read the object. For your example, however, I would just call the getter and setter methods!

Comment: interesting point using Serialization for saving the state and retrieval. but is it not costlier/affects performance?

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you're concerned about performance, though, using a `List` is still preferable, as that's basically the only way to get the control over access you want.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you mean list instead of array. but that would still contain mutable objects?

Comment: Oh, of course; there's nothing you can do about mutable objects under any circumstances.  But you can refuse to change the references held in a list, unlike an array.

Answer (score 1):

In your modifySome method, return a new Some[] array.

```
Some[] modifySome(Some[] passedArray){
  Some[] result = new Some[passedArray.length];
  System.arraycopy( passedArray, 0, result , 0, a.length );
  //Modify result as needed
  return result
}
```

If you cange modifySome to return an array, your code can change to:

```
Some[] some = modifySome(someFirst);
```

After that line, `someFirst` will still be the same as it was before and `some` will be the modified values.

Comment: I didnot get you? I'm afraid the modify is a void method

Comment: Can you change it to return an array?

Comment: @assylias To do that, the `Clonable` interface has to be implemented and the clone method may have to be overridden. Also, I do not believe that `clone` performs a deep copy of arrays.

Comment: @AnthonyW clone on an array does exactly the same thing as arraycopy. And neither is a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Some> someFirst = checkPrev.getSomeVals();
Iterator iterator = someFirst.iterator();
modifySome(some);
```

The iterator will still be referring to the original list, not to the modified list.

Another option is to make a copy of the original array.

```
Some[] someFirst = checkPrev.getSomeVals();
Some[] someCopy = new Some[someFirst.length];
System.arrayCopy(someFirst, 0, someCopy, 0, someFirst.length);
modifySome(some);
```

`someCopy` will still hold a copy of the original array.

Comment: I think this the solution I am looking for. Please elaborate on the first option. I am unable to assign an array to the list, compiler error

Comment: @user1782556 The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a replacement for the array; `array[i] = some` is analogous to `list.set(i, some)`, and `some = array[i]` is analogous to `some = list.get(i)`

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I guess you mean something like this. CopyOnWriteArrayList someList = new ArrayList<Some>(Arrays.asList<someFirst>); Please correct if iam wrong..

Comment: @user1782556 What I mean is that if you take an iterator of the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and then modify the list, then the iterator will still refer to the original `CopyOnWriteArrayList` without your having to take an explicit copy.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot it didnot work. the values in the iterator changes. I did - add the values of the array to the list in a iteration. then initiated a iterator for the particular list, but after modification the values changed in the iterator.

Comment: @user1782556 Each time you get an iterator it references the latest snapshot, not the original snapshot.  I recommend you use `System.arrayCopy` on primitive arrays, or else make copies of an `ArrayList` with `ArrayList copy = new ArrayList(originalArrayList)` as you mentioned in your comment, instead of a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` if you want better control over the snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the mutable world of Java beans.

You cannot do what you want to do... But here is a solution using a couple of interfaces I wrote:

```
// Both classes in the same package

@Immutable // by contract
class Some implements Frozen<SomeBuilder>
{
    // All fields are final, package local
    final String name;

    // getters only -- NO setters

    public Some(final SomeBuilder builder)
    {
        name = builder.name;
        // other
    }

    // Return a thawed version
    @Override
    public SomeBuilder thaw()
    {
        return new SomeBuilder(this);
    }
}

@NotThreadSafe // by contract
class SomeBuilder implements Thawed<Some>
{
    // Mutable fields here, package local
    String name;
    // other

    // To create a new builder
    public SomeBuilder()
    {
    }

    // Package local constructor
    SomeBuilder(final Some some)
    {
        name = some.name;
        // etc
    }

    // Mutations
    public SomeBuilder setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    // Return a frozen version
    @Override
    public Some freeze()
    {
        return new Some(this);
    }
}
```

Now, as to your modify function, make it return a NEW array. And use `.freeze()`/`.thaw()` to create new instances of `Some` from existing ones.

Comment: Thanks but cannot modify the class? by the way wil try this next time

Answer (score 0):

One of the weaknesses with Java is that there is fundamentally only one non-primitive type: the promiscuous heap object reference.  There is no way that an instance of class `George` which holds a reference to a object `Foo` of class `Bar` outside its package can share that reference with outside code without giving that outside code the perpetual ability to do anything to `Foo` that `George` can do with it.  Part of the design goal of Java is to be easy to implement even on simple hardware systems, and having a single non-primitive type helps it achieve that goal.  On the other hand, it also means that the programmer is required to keep track of which object references serve to encapsulate:

- Immutable aspects of object state other than identity, which cannot be changed even by code which holds a reference.
- Object identity (as well as, perhaps, other immutable aspects of state)
- Aspects of object state which would be mutable, *except that they are expected never to be given to code that would actually mutate them*, but not identity.
- Mutable aspects of object state which are "owned" by the code which hold the reference, but not identity.
- Mutable aspects of object state, *as well as* identity.

In your code, because arrays are mutable, your array-type field cannot have the first meaning, but it could hold any of the other four.  In addition, the elements of the array could hold any of the above kinds of things.  If you consider the state of your object to be the combination of `id` and `name` pairs held in its array, if the `id` and/or `name` of a `Some` to which the `Check` holds a reference could change, *and if such a change would be considered a change in the state of the `Check`*, then making a copy of the `Check`'s state would require creating a new array, and populating it with new `Some` instances whose data is copied from the corresponding instances in the original array.

If none of the `Check` objects which are in the array will ever be exposed to code that might mutate them, then it would not be necessary to construct new instances of the individual `Check` objects; creating a new array and populating it with references to the objects in the original array would suffice.  Likewise if the purpose of the array is to encapsulate the *identities* of `Check` objects which are defined elsewhere and thus changes to those objects would not be considered changes to the `Check`'s state.  Note that in the former situation (the objects never change), replacing the `Some` objects with new instances that hold the same data would be inefficient but would not break anything.  In the latter situation (the array encapsulates the *identities* of the objects, rather than their states), replacing the references with references to new instances would break the code.

While many people talk about "deep cloning" or "shallow cloning", such terminology mainly stems from the lack of clarity about what various object references are supposed to encapsulate.  If object `Fred` has a class-type field that encapsulates mutable state which `Fred` owns (but does not encapsulate identity), a copy of the `Fred` should hold a reference to a copy of that object.  If a field encapsulates immutable state, a copy of `Fred` could hold a reference to the original object or any immutable copy thereof.  If it encapsulates identity, a copy of `Fred` *must* hold a reference to the original object--not a copy.  If it encapsulates both identity and mutable state, then `Fred` cannot be copied without also copying the entire forest of inter-connected objects of which it is a part.